Change the background by clicking on the button
I need to change the background color at the same time as changing the image by clicking on the button. Darkening the background works completely, but how do I change the background by clicking on the button? I was looking for it, but it didn't work out, please help me.


document.getElementById('hide-checkbox').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const currentTheme = document.body.className;
  if (currentTheme === 'light-theme') {
    document.body.className = 'dark-theme';
    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'css/Style.css');
  } else {
    document.body.className = 'light-theme';
    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'css/Style.css');
  }
});
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-image: url("https://sun9-66.userapi.com/impg/U_B0e4HYLxsYNJIxFpYW6jR12JhDy76x2zhkXw/O4OafXIrfLc.jpg?size=2560x1920&quality=95&sign=c9143650a2af6853e49e25e18475c8f4&type=album");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
<div class="image">
  <input type="checkbox" id="hide-checkbox">
  <label for="hide-checkbox" class="toggle">
    <span class="toggle-button">
      <span class="crater crater-1"></span>
      <span class="crater crater-2"></span>
      <span class="crater crater-3"></span>
      <span class="crater crater-4"></span>
      <span class="crater crater-5"></span>
      <span class="crater crater-6"></span>
      <span class="crater crater-7"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="star star-1"></span>
    <span class="star star-2"></span>
    <span class="star star-3"></span>
    <span class="star star-4"></span>
    <span class="star star-5"></span>
    <span class="star star-6"></span>
    <span class="star star-7"></span>
    <span class="star star-8"></span>
  </label>
</div>




You update the body's class name, but there's no corresponding css that goes with each class.

Also, you set theme in localStorage to the same string in each case.

Here is the full code. You need to write CSS for changing colors. Change background urls and try...
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      /* background-image: url("https://sun9-66.userapi.com/impg/U_B0e4HYLxsYNJIxFpYW6jR12JhDy76x2zhkXw/O4OafXIrfLc.jpg?size=2560x1920&quality=95&sign=c9143650a2af6853e49e25e18475c8f4&type=album"); */
      /* background-position: center center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-size: cover; */
    }

    body.dark-theme {
      background-color: #131313;
      color: #dfdfdf;
    }

    body.light-theme {
      background-color: #dfdfdf;
      color: #131313;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body class="light-theme">
  <div class="image">
    <input type="checkbox" id="hide-checkbox">
    <h1>Theme Demo</h1>
    <label for="hide-checkbox" class="toggle">
      <span class="toggle-button">
        <span class="crater crater-1"></span>
        <span class="crater crater-2"></span>
        <span class="crater crater-3"></span>
        <span class="crater crater-4"></span>
        <span class="crater crater-5"></span>
        <span class="crater crater-6"></span>
        <span class="crater crater-7"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="star star-1"></span>
      <span class="star star-2"></span>
      <span class="star star-3"></span>
      <span class="star star-4"></span>
      <span class="star star-5"></span>
      <span class="star star-6"></span>
      <span class="star star-7"></span>
      <span class="star star-8"></span>
    </label>

    <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        const themeBtn = document.querySelector('#hide-checkbox');
        themeBtn.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
          if (e.currentTarget.checked) {
            document.body.classList.add("dark-theme");
            document.body.classList.remove("light-theme");
            // document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(someurl)';
          } else {
            // document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(anotherurl)';
            document.body.classList.add("light-theme");
            document.body.classList.remove("dark-theme");
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
</body>

</html>


How exactly are the dark-theme and light-theme classes supposed to affect anything?

I think you need body.classList.add('someClass') and body.classList.remove('someClass')
Answering for a SO tutorial, so please be polite with me :)

This is one way to do it, and my preferred way, especially when dealing with multiple classes. But I believe OP's setting of the className works fine in this case.
